# Добавление событий в calendar-widget

Tags: calendar, виджет

Как добавить в приложение с открытым кодом calendar-widget (https://github.com/plusonelabs/calendar-widget) собственное событие (напоминание, день рождения и др.).

Comment: Вам необходимо привести пример проблемного участка кода, чтобы вам смогли помочь